# Error in Sequential Animation XML

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am using animation in that. I am getting compile time Error in Using sequential Animation.

The error is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'pivotX' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromXScale' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toXScale' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toYScale' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'duration' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromYScale' in package 
     'android '
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'pivotY' in package 
     'android '
```

And My xml Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>


    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

Can anyone tell me why it is cause of ?

Comment: where have you placed this xml in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" **<----- remove space**
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>


    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace below line everywhere

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
```

with

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

There is extra white space at end.

**EDIT :**
**For `AnimationListener`**

Write this in `onWindowFocusChanged()`

```
Animation anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    HomeScreenActivity.this, R.anim.translate);
img_main.startAnimation(anim_translate);

anim_translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // start another activity
                }
            });
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks..... but how to wait the effect of control till the animation complete

Comment: means you want something to happen once your animation is done. is this you want ?

Comment: No I mean I cant see animation effect because when I click on button which I had applied animation another activity started so I cant see effect.

Comment: so you can implement `AnimationListener`. and in `onAnimationEnd()`, start your required activity.

Comment: No I hadent Use AnimationListener. Is there any other way for that?

Comment: why you cannot use `AnimationListener` in your case ?

Comment: Ok what I need to do in Animation Listener